# java calling method expecting List<Object> with List<String>

Tags: java

I have this static method declared in class A as follows :

```
public static boolean staticMethod(List<Object> list)
```

and I want to call it as follows

```
List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
boolean b = A.staticMethod(list);
```

Why does it not compile ?

```
The method staticMethod(List<Object>) in the type ArrayListHelper is not applicable for the arguments (List<String>)
```

I want to write a generic method doing specific handlings on List objects holding objects from a subclass of Object.

Thanks.

Comment: What you want is for `staticMethod` to accept a `List<?>`.

Comment: @LouisWasserman Ugly. What he wants is a generic list. The wildcard is sometimes useful but to avoid 90% of the time

Comment: @Dici that's what `List<?>` gets them, and that's the proper way the language provides to get it.  Not sure what's "ugly" about that.  Did you mean raw types?

Comment: `List<?>` is pretty much like a raw type isn't it ? It's just specifying explicitely that you don't care about the type, but it has the same properties as a raw type. I would prefer `static <T> void method(List<T> list)`.

Comment: @Dici no, it's not like a raw type. It says that the method accepts a generic list, and that its generic type can be anything. Since it doesn't have any other argument that is related to T, and doesn't return a type related to T, it has absolutely no reason to be generic. See http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#reverse-java.util.List- for example, which has the same signature, for the same reason. Just for your information, Louis has designed and implemented a big part of Guava collections. I think he knows how to deal with generic collections :)

Comment: @JBNizet yeah, I was going through the same thought process at the moment. If it does not have to return something generic, why even bother. Moreover, I wrote some snippets that show it's indeed different from a raw type. For example, the raw type will let you add anything to the list while the wilcard will prevent this to happen. This solution is actually nice and safe. My bad !